# List out grabbable windows for FFMPEG to capture

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a command to list out windows that ffmpeg can capture? ? In this [article](https://blog.petehouston.com/list-all-connected-media-devices-in-windows/), the command

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

can list out all connected media devices in Windows OS. Is there an argument (maybe like `list_windows`?) that can show all possible windows that can be captured. I see a SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43273058/13642249) that mentions how to look at different tabs/windows of firefox with

```
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" /fo list | findstr  Window
```

However, I'm not sure how to proceed with Linux.

Comment: No such feature.